# Char and Int in one Array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, char, int

I want to have chars and ints inside one array. What i am trying to do is have 1 to 9 in my array and the user selects which number to replace with the letter X. How can i have this done? I assume i cant pass chars into an array that is called as `int array[8];` So is there a way to have both ints and chars in an array?

Comment: There is almost certainly a better way to do what you want to do, although I don't really know what it is because I can't really understand what you want to do.

Comment: I want to have an array that is numbers 1 to 9. And i wantt o replace 1 to 9 when i choose which one to replace with the letter X. Basically how can i replace an array that has ints with letters in certain positions. I am assuming i cant put Chars into a place that has Ints

Comment: Would it not make more sense to have a separate variable to record which index the user chose, then make use of that in the relevant place in your app? Is there any reason why you are set on having this information stored in one place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In c++ `int`s and `char`s are **almost** the same thing. They are both stored as numbers, just with different resolutions.

```
int array[2];
array[0] = 100;
array[1] = 'c';

printf("%d", array[0]) //Prints the number at index zero.

//Is it %c to print a char?
printf("%c", array[1]) //Prints the number at index zero as it's equivalent char.
```

Comment: The cast to `char` is pointless; as `printf` is a variadic function, it will be promoted back to an `int`.

Comment: I have a forloop that adds 1 to 9 inside an char array but when i print it i get little images and not numbers

Comment: ditch the cast, varargs functions don't receive integral types smaller than `int`

Comment: @Oli and Ben, cast-be-gone.  Mystycs - That's because the numbers 1 to 9 don't represent printable characters.  Try storing the numbers 65+ as an example instead

Comment: @mystycs: Those are the characters corresponding to the numbers 1...9.  The numbers corresponding to the characters '1'...'9' are not 1...9, on an ASCII system they would be 0x31 (49) ... 0x39 (57).  Frequently you will find yourself adding or subtracting '0' to convert between the numeric value and character value.

Comment: OHH So i should specifiy them according to ASCII so then 49 to 57 would be 1 to 9 right?

Comment: I GOT IT!! I love you! hahaha

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just use an array of characters?

You can do

```
char characters[] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 0}; // last one is NULL terminator

int replace = 1;
cout << "Enter the number you want to replace with X: ";
cin >> replace;

assert(replace > 0 && replace < 10); // or otherwise check validity of input

characters[replace - 1] = 'X';

// print the string
cout << characters;

// if the user entered 5, it would print
// 1234X6789
```

Answer (score 0):

A stab in the dark, because there is a large distinction between the user-model and the programming model.

When the user 'inserts' a character at a specified index, you want to update an array of char instead of inserting the value in your int array. Maintain the 2 side-by-side.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, `char` will be promoted to `int` when you assign elements of the `int[]` array with `char` values. You would have to use an explicit cast when you are reading from that array.

I.e., the following works

```
int a[10];
char c='X';

a[0] = c;
c = (char) a[0];
```

HOWEVER,

Since you would need to keep track of which elements hold ints and which hold chars -- this is not an attractive solution.

Another option is just have an array of `char` and store the digits 0..9 as chars. I.e., '0','1', ..'9'.

(A third option is just have another variable store the index to the 'X' element -- but this is very different than what you are suggesting)

Answer (score 0):

You can treat your numbers as characters

```
    char mychar[10];
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
    {
        mychar[i] = '0' + i;
    }


    //Assume you read it 
    int userInput = 9;
    mychar[userInput-1] = 'X';
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use -1 instead of X assuming that your array does not have any negative numbers. I have done that before.